# java.lang.ref.Finalizer piled up

Tags: memory-leaks, mat, finalizer

We see memory usage of a container keeps going up. I see an extra leak suspect Finalizer that keeps increasing as shown in the snapshots attached.

We do not have an override method for finalize() at all. The jdk version is 11.0.7.
From gc log, I see that the following log runs every few minutes:

> [2024-01-24T01:23:16.770+0000][1183057ms] GC(107) Concurrent Cycle

Is this a known GC issue?

Tried on MAT to find the referent but it is not obvious from the objects_list view.

[image]

[image]

How to decode the .hprof file on MAT?